# Is there any method inside the AudioContext can let ByteTimeDomainData back to the sound?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, web-audio-api, webkitaudiocontext, audiocontext

The following code is where I can put the current TimeDomainData into an array.

```
    fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(fbc_array);
```

And then I can use the for statement to let each `fbc_array[i]` value (Time Domain waveform) being displayed on canvas.

**Question:**

I want to use the mouse events to trigger the sound where the mouse hovers on the Time Domain waveform.

Is there any method inside the AudioContext can let the `fbc_array[i]` value back to the sound?

Comment: Why not normalize the mouse position and map it to time, then play from that time to n length? If you want to *change* the data you would need to go through the scripting node.

Comment: I've think about your solution… And it's intutive one! I'll give it a try!

Comment: BTW, what's the scripting mode you've talked about? Is that inside the AudioContext? Thanks first~~

Comment: yes, it's on the context. See [createScriptProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createScriptProcessor) for details. Are you playing a long audio track, ie. using the Audio element as source for its buffering capability? If so, you can set the new time directly on the audio element from the normalized mouse position.

Comment: OK! I'll try~ because I wanna try to create the granular effect by using this technique inside the UI performing ! Thanks a lot for your help!!